# Add Library to Visual Studio 2008 C++ Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mapi

I'm completely new to Visual Studio and I'm having some trouble getting a project started with Visual Studio 2008.  I'm experimenting with MAPI, and I'm getting error messages like this when I go to build the project:

"unresolved external symbol _MAPIUninitialize@0 referenced in function _main"

I know I need to link to MAPI32.lib, but the guides I have found thus far have indicated going to the "Visual Studio settings **link** tab" and adding it there (which was - apparently - from an older version of Visual Studio).  I can't find anything like that in the project properties linker or C/C++ sections of VS 2008.

Where do I need to tell Visual Studio to use that library?

Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's under Project Properties / Configuration Properties / Linker / Input / Additional Dependencies.

The help tip at the bottom of the screen says *"Specifies additional items add to the line line (ex: kernel32.lib)"*.

Comment: Wow, M$ really buried this setting.  You'd think they would make it a little easier.  At first glance it seems like the Add References link would work, but no.  This answer is very useful.  Thanks!

Comment: For anyone who also needs to know how to set the library path -- it's Project Properties / Configuration Proerties / Linker / General / Additional Library Directories

Answer (score 12):

Project Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies

You can also use
`#pragma comment( lib, "mapi32" )`
in one of your source files. As noted MSDN here is a similar library addition using the pragma technique [MSDN - Creating a Basic Winsock Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Three simple steps:

1. Project Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories
   choose the folder which contains your .lib file

2.Project Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies
Just enter the name of your .lib files

3.Project Properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories
choose the folder where your .h files locate

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to just drag'n'drop library file to project in Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Do not statically link to any MAPI dlls. You must always dynamically load the MAPI system - look at the MFCMAPI source code to see how it is done: http://mfcmapi.codeplex.com/