# Linker error lnk2001 in VS2008

Tags: c++, linker

I am getting linker errors lnk2001. i am very new to vs2008 and not sure how to make my prog work with cryptopp library. know how to link it? instruction so i don't get that undefined symbols stuff?

Comment: Please paste the exact error.  It sounds like you're using the include files, but not linking to the lib.

Comment: i will post the error message. but you are 100% correct i am not linking to the crytopp library reason being that i don't know how to make vs2008 uses the library. so, is there a way to make vs2008 point to the cryptopp lib??

Comment: @user248247 - check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114914/add-library-to-visual-studio-2008-c-project

Comment: @djones2010 : See [.lib Files as Linker Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba1z7822(VS.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

creating and using static libs in VS2008
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

something similar with DLLs
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636%28v=VS.90%29.aspx