# C++ What .lib file should I include

Tags: c++, winapi, linker-errors, wfp

I am doing a firewall application. For that I tried some codes from codeproject  [HERE](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/PacketFilter.aspx)

But the problem is the code is not compiling, giving linking error. I am using SDK 2008. Can anyone please tell me what .lib file should I use for WFP and where can I find it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Fwpuclnt.lib` is the one you need - check out the [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364040%28VS.85%29.aspx) for the functions you are using on MSDN, they tell you in the 'Requirements' section what lib exports a given API.

You need the correct [SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=e6e1c3df-a74f-4207-8586-711ebe331cdc&displaylang=en) to use this.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. But I have another problem as I am not a c++ programmer I dont know how to add it to my project. Would you please help me out on that. Thanks again.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114914/add-library-to-visual-studio-2008-c-project

Answer (score 1):

MSDN tells you on the bottom of every page describing a function which lib file is required. In the case of those firewall related functions it's `fwpuclnt.lib`.

If that still doesn't help, it'd be easier to help if you include the actual error messages.

Comment: Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FwpmEngineOpen0@20 referenced in function "private: unsigned long __thiscall PacketFilter::CreateDeleteInterface(bool)" (?CreateDeleteInterface@PacketFilter@@AAEK_N@Z) PacketFilter.obj FirewallVista