# Configuring LAPACK in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 with Intel Visual Fortran Compiler

Tags: visual-studio-2008, lapack

I have developed a project which requires LAPACK functions. I have developed it in MACINTOSH using GFORTRAN as compiler and "framework -vecLib" command to build. "vecLib" is LAPACK alternative provided by apple.

Now I need to implement the same project in Windows 64bit machine. I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 with Intel Visual FORTRAN compiler installed. I have implemented the source files and ready to go, except there is no LAPACK linked with my VS2008.

I have been browsing through internet for solution and found few websites which provides some comments but I couldn't get things work properly using those information.

I would truly appreciate if some one can give me a detailed step by step procedure to link LAPACK with my project.

Thanks for help,

Amitava

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Intel Fortran, you might have MKL library bundled with it. Here's [a KB article from Intel](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-math-kernel-library-intel-mkl-for-windows-build-intel-mkl-program-with-intel-fortran-in-microsoft-visual-studio/).

Comment: Unfortunately, my installation does not include MKL library. I checked with my IT department and they also said this package is not included with educational license.

So, I need to figure out a way to do it for free, i.e. using LAPACK directly. Please let me know if you know how to set up LAPACK.

Comment: well then, the easiest way would be to get the reference implementation from netlib, compile it and link your project against it. Which isn't too hard as far as I can recollect [been quite a while since I'd to do exactly that.]

Comment: I am stuck at linking the LAPACK after generating the lapack.lib file. I just don't know how to link a library file in Visual Studio 2008. Wish someone can guide me.

Comment: Having never used Visual Studio 2008 myself, googling for "visual studion 2008 linking" gives a pageful of resourses. For example, this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114914/add-library-to-visual-studio-2008-c-project