# unresolved external symbol _gluLookAt@72 referenced in function

Tags: opengl, glu

I'm making a program using the glu library but when i compile i got this error:

```
1>opengl_3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gluLookAt@72 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall OpenGLContext::setupScene(void)" (?setupScene@OpenGLContext@@QAEXXZ)
```

I included GL/glu.h and checked if the lib and dll were present. (they are by default)
I'm using visual studio 2012.

Any idea where this error is coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not linking to glu. Add glu to the libraries against which your program should be linked. A more detailed description can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114914/add-library-to-visual-studio-2008-c-project).

Comment: Thanks a lot , I just add 
#pragma comment(lib, "glu32.lib")

But i saw glu32.dll in system32 so I thought it should work